# Adding to a one-to-many relationship not updating UI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a one-to-many relationship in core data of *plan* -> *recipe*. *plan.recipes* is of type *NSSet?*, so I have created custom NSManagedObject classes with computed properties to convert these into arrays, adding an extra property *recipesArray*:

```
public var recipesArray: [Recipe] {
    let set = recipes as? Set<Recipe> ?? []
    
    return set.sorted {
        $0.wrappedName < $1.wrappedName
    }
}
```

I then display this list in a View using a ForEach, using the *recipesArray* property. A subview of this view calls *plan.addToRecipes(recipe: Recipe)*, to add a new object to the relationship. I then save.

The issue is, the ForEach in the parent view does not react to this addition. If I refresh the view by navigating away, then the new recipe is shown, but the View is not automatically updated when the new recipe is added.

Does anyone know how to do this? Should I be using the original *recipes* property instead of this custom array one?

Comment: Make sure that `plan` is wrapped in an `@ObservedObject`. Also, `recipes.allObjects` is probably better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make another `FetchRequest` for `Recipe`s using a predicate that equals a given `plan`, e.g. something like this:

```
struct RecipesView: View {
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Recipe>
    var recipes: FetchedResults<Recipe> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }

    init(plan: Plan) {
        let sortDescriptors = ...
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "plan = %@", plan)
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate, animation: .default)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(recipes) { recipe in
            RecipeView(recipe: recipe) // it's important to not access recipe's properties (firing a fault) until inside a sub-view's body.
        }
    }
}
```

Note: There is currently a bug in `FetchRequest` that results in body always invoked even when this `View` is init with the same `plan` and thus same `FetchRequest`. This is because the `FetchRequest` struct inits a new object inside it every time, causing it and consequently this View to appear as changed to SwiftUI. I [reported this bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5516608613122048) so hopefully they fix it. You could workaround it in the meantime with a wrapper `View` that takes the `plan` as a let so body won't be called.